# Using local users as MySQL users

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have a Linux (Ubuntu) server.

When i want to add a new site to my server, i'm adding a user to linux via SSH

```
adduser domaincom
passwd password
```

through vsftpd's `local_user` and `chroot_local_user` options, this user can reach to own *home* directory via FTP.

I don't have any problem on setting FTP but i want to do same thing on MySQL .
I want to use local system users as MYSQL users (and passwords as their passwords). Are there any option for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. MySQL uses its own authentication database -- additionally, since it's generally necessary to put the username and password in a configuration file for web applications, MySQL should almost certainly use a separate password from FTP.